# Broken masonry layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using `columns` class in TailwindCSS to make mansory layout but it broken height of element. How I can fix it?

Here's my code:

```
        <div className="columns-2 gap-4">
                <div className="block h-[120px] mb-4 bg-[#0000ff]">                                            
                </div>

                <div className="block h-[120px] mb-4 bg-red-500">                                            
                </div>

                <div className="block h-[120px] mb-4 bg-[#2e8b57]">                                            
                </div>                
        </div>
```

Current layout is broken:

[image]

My playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/15N8OXhSMN

It looks like it is limited in height even though there are not the parent elements have a fixed height property. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you make a working demo?  I put your code into the Tailwind playground and I cannot reproduce what is in your screenshot: https://play.tailwindcss.com/aFF2Dvopyu

Comment: @ChrisBarr yes, please help me check it  https://play.tailwindcss.com/15N8OXhSMN

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a layout with two columns, but you do not want the red square to be broken up in the middle between the two columns.

For that I recommend using grid layouts to define 2 columns and 2 rows. The grid flow will be "grid-flow-col" so your squares can be places vertically in order. Your code will look like:

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-2 grid-rows-2 gap-4">
  <div class="mb-4 block h-[120px] w-full bg-[#0000ff]"></div>

  <div class="mb-4 block h-[120px] w-full bg-red-500"></div>

  <div class="mb-4 block h-[120px] w-full bg-[#2e8b57]"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found the cause, because I specified the child element as a `block` element, to fix it I just replace by `inline-block` and it work like a charm. Oh my god, I spent 5 hours for this problem. Thank you for your help. I will take note!